androidx.profileinstaller.ProfileInstallReceiver is found on release build with android:exported="true". Does it create any security issue?
When I analyze my Manifest file of my apk, I found that androidx.profileinstaller.ProfileInstallReceiver  is added with android:exported="true". The receiver is not present on my merged manifest but it is found only on release Manifest file. How can I remove it from my rellease manifest file?. Does it create any issue if removed it from my manifest file? If I include it in my release manifest, does it create any security vulnerability?
You can find the code snippet below.
<receiver
    android:name="androidx.profileinstaller.ProfileInstallReceiver"
    android:permission="android.permission.DUMP"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true"
    android:directBootAware="false">

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="androidx.profileinstaller.action.INSTALL_PROFILE" />
    </intent-filter>

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="androidx.profileinstaller.action.SKIP_FILE" />
    </intent-filter>

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="androidx.profileinstaller.action.SAVE_PROFILE" />
    </intent-filter>

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="androidx.profileinstaller.action.BENCHMARK_OPERATION" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>


I analysed the code and understood that it is included from jetified-profileinstaller, which I did not include in my build.gradle dependencies
